# animation accordion using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

```css
#accordion {
  .card {
    border: unset !important;
    .card-header {
      @extend .text-xx-large;
      background-color: $white;
      padding: ($spacer * 3.44) 0px ($spacer * 3.44) 0px;
    }
  }
}

.card-header {
  h5 {
   a{
      color: $dark;
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      padding-right: ($spacer * 2.5);
      font-size: ($spacer * 1.5);

      &:hover, &:focus, &:active {
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      &::before {
        content: "\f28e";
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 0;
        font-family: "LineAwesome";
        color: $green;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 24px;
        font-size: 24px;
        transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0deg);
        transition: .35s all ease-in-out;
      }

      &.collapsed::before {
        content: "\F2C2";
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 0;
        font-family: "LineAwesome";
        color: $green;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 24px;
        font-size: 24px;
        transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
        transition: .35s all ease-in-out;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/fonts/line-awesome/1.1/css/line-awesome-font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        <a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have following code using bootstrap 4 and  line-awesome icons,jquery ,css.I was tried to run this code but what i  want it didn't come .I want
when i clicked that link the icons didn't appeared in right corner  I want when we  seen the accordion ,the plus icon will be  displayed .after that when i clicked that link it will appeared minus icon . plz give some suggestion

Comment: Dear @kajol are you trying to display + or - icon?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Just updated your answer. I have added icons on the basis of class that appears on `a` tag when we click on it. I hope it would be useful to you.

```css
#accordion {
  .card {
    border: unset !important;
    .card-header {
      @extend .text-xx-large;
      background-color: $white;
      padding: ($spacer * 3.44) 0px ($spacer * 3.44) 0px;
    }
  }
}

.card-header {
  h5 {
   a{
      color: $dark;
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      padding-right: ($spacer * 2.5);
      font-size: ($spacer * 1.5);
      display: block;

      &:hover, &:focus, &:active {
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      &::before {
        content: "\f28e";
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 0;
        font-family: "LineAwesome";
        color: $green;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 24px;
        font-size: 24px;
        transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0deg);
        transition: .35s all ease-in-out;
      }

      &.collapsed::before {
        content: "\F2C2";
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 0;
        font-family: "LineAwesome";
        color: $green;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 24px;
        font-size: 24px;
        transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
        transition: .35s all ease-in-out;
      }
    }
  }
}


h5 a.btn {display: block; text-align:left;}
h5 a.btn {background: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/25/25336.svg') no-repeat right center; background-size: 24px auto;}
h5 a.btn.collapsed{background: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/9/9129.svg') no-repeat right center; background-size: 24px auto;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/fonts/line-awesome/1.1/css/line-awesome-font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        <a>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added working example for you https://jsfiddle.net/wd87u0xL/2/.

The main idea is to use `FontAwesome` font-family rather than `LineAwesome`. And also please fix closing `</a>` tag for the third item in collapse.

Also you can simplify your code because `a::before` and `a.collapsed::before` have common things:

```
a {
   &::before {
       content: "\f28e";
       position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       right: 0;
       font-family: FontAwesome;
       color: $green;
       font-weight: 400;
       line-height: 24px;
       font-size: 24px;
       transition: .35s all ease-in-out;
       transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0deg);
   }

   &.collapsed::before {
       content: "\F2C2";
       transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.